# Numerical convergence of a sum

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, exponential-sum, theta-functions

I want to study the convergence of the function given below.

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} e^{-\Gamma^2 n^2} $$

The $n$ are integers!

Here, if we check numerically, the function converges based on $\Gamma^2$ I believe. Is there a way to define a value of Number of summation elements $ N $ where the summation converges numerically?

The infinite sum given by mathematica is the following,

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} e^{-\Gamma^2 n^2} = EllipticTheta[3, 0, e^{-\Gamma^2}] $$

I want an expression for the number of elements to sum where it converges numerically.

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} e^{-\Gamma^2 n^2} \sim \sum_{n = 1}^{N} e^{-\Gamma^2 n^2} $$

Therefore, I need,

$$ N = f(\Gamma^2) $$

Is it possible?

For example, for a $\Gamma^2 = 0.17546$, the value of $N$ I observed on MATLAB is 7.

Comment: What is your question? The partial sums approach the series more and more as $N\to\infty$. The number of terms required depends on what accuracy you want for the series.

Comment: For example, let say I want an accuracy of 10^(-4). Then, can we find a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an accuracy of $\varepsilon > 0$ (e.g. $\varepsilon=10^{-4}$, as mentioned in comments), it means that you need to find such $N$ that
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-\Gamma^2 n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^{N} e^{-\Gamma^2 n^2}\right| = \left|\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} e^{-\Gamma^2 n^2}\right| = \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} e^{-\Gamma^2 n^2} < \varepsilon 
$$
Observe that
$$
\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} e^{-\Gamma^2 n^2} = \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}
e^{-\Gamma^2(n^2 - n)} e^{-\Gamma^2 n} \leq 
\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} e^{-\Gamma^2(N^2 + N)} e^{-\Gamma^2 n} = 
e^{-\Gamma^2(N^2 + N)} \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}e^{-\Gamma^2 n}
$$
The inequality is due to $n^2 - n = n(n-1) \geq (N+1)N$ for $n\geq N+1$.
By the geometric series sum formula,
$$
\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}e^{-\Gamma^2 n} = \frac{e^{-\Gamma^2 (N+1)}}{1 - e^{-\Gamma^2}},
$$
so
$$
\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} e^{-\Gamma^2 n^2} \leq e^{-\Gamma^2 (N^2 + N)} \cdot \frac{e^{-\Gamma^2 (N+1)}}{1 - e^{-\Gamma^2}} = \frac{e^{-\Gamma^2(N+1)^2}}{1 - e^{-\Gamma^2}}
$$
and it's needed to solve $\frac{e^{-\Gamma^2(N+1)^2}}{1 - e^{-\Gamma^2}} < \varepsilon$:
$$
\frac{e^{-\Gamma^2(N+1)^2}}{1 - e^{-\Gamma^2}} < \varepsilon \Leftrightarrow
e^{-\Gamma^2(N+1)^2} < \varepsilon \cdot \left(1 - e^{-\Gamma^2}\right) \Leftrightarrow \\ \Leftrightarrow \Gamma^2 (N+1)^2 > -\ln \varepsilon - \ln \left(1 - e^{-\Gamma^2}\right) \Leftrightarrow N + 1 > \frac{1}{\Gamma}\sqrt{- \ln \varepsilon - \ln \left(1 - e^{-\Gamma^2}\right)}
$$
So, $N = f(\Gamma) = \left\lceil\frac{1}{\Gamma}\sqrt{- \ln \varepsilon - \ln \left(1 - e^{-\Gamma^2}\right)}  - 1 \right\rceil$. Here is also a Desmos [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uors3tddow) for testing this bound.